# Dividing range into N equal numbers

Tags: c, matlab

I am trying to implement the linspace function of Matlab in C. I am confused about how to make that algorithm..

If suppose I have a number s=6.. then the range would be -6 to 6.

If Even..

And in this range if i need suppose 4 equal numbers then the output would be -6, -2, 2, 6.

If i need 6 equal numbers then the output would be -6, -3.6, -1.2, 1.2, 3.6, 6.

If Odd..

If I need suppose 5 equal numbers then the output would be -6, -3, 0, 3, 6

If I need suppose 7 equal numbers then the output would be -6, -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6

How can i approach this process?

Comment: Keep on adding `(stop_num-start_num)/(N-1)` starting with the `start_num` till `stop_num` in a loop?

Comment: Type `open linspace` in Matlab and see its source code

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is correct. But taking your example. s=6, range = -6 to 6

case: even n=4
-6 to 6, we have 12 units, `12/(n-1) = size of a single unit = 12/(4-1) = 4`
So starting from `-6, (-6+4)=-2, (-2+4)=2, (4+2)=6`

case: odd n=5
one number is 0. Now we need 4 numbers, 2 on left of 0, 2 on right of 0.
-6 to 0 we have 6 units/2 = 3
So starting from `-6, (-6+3)=3, 0, (0+3)=3, (3+3)=6`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void findRange(int n, int gaps)   {
    int totalRange = 2*n;
    ArrayList rangeValues = new ArrayList();
    if(totalRange%gaps == 0)
    {
        int gapValInt = totalRange / gaps;  
        int j=0;
        for(int i = -n ; i <=n ; i=i+gapValInt )
        {
            rangeValues.add(i);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        float val;
        float gapValFloat = (float)totalRange / gaps;
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= gaps ; i++)
        {
            val = -n + gapValFloat * i; 
            rangeValues.add(Math.round(val*10.0)/10.0);
        }
    }
    for(Object o : rangeValues)
    {
        System.out.println(o.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this is not in matlab, as I dont have the sw at this moment. Still you can find the logic behind the solution. If not let me know, I can provide pseudo code as well.

Comment: Last for loop is for printing the values found in said range, you can omit that, that is not part of algo. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `linspace(a, b, n)` could be implemented like this (in pseudocode):

```
step = (b-a)/(n-1)
return (a, a+step*1, a+step*2, ..., b)
```

in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *
linspace(int a, int b, int n) {
    int i;
    float *arr, step;

    arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * n);
    if (arr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        return NULL;
    }

    step = (b - a)/(n-1.0);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = a + step * i;
    }

    return arr;
}
```